# Nominalized Infinitives or nouns formed from verbs using the suffix "-ung"

Tags: nominalization, suffix

I was reading Sherlock Holmes in German with translations given in English to aid German learners. And I encountered this sentence (which makes complete sense to me):

"**Durch Verwendung eines dicken Lexikonbandes** stellte er fest, dass das Papier in einer Papiermühle in Böhmen hergestellt worden war."

My book has translated this as:

"**By using** a thick book of encyclopedias, he discovered that the paper had been made in a paper mill in Bohemia."

What puzzled me is the use of **Durch Verwendung** instead of using a Nominalized infinitive i.e. **Durch Verwenden**, since I'm given to understand that '*Durch+Nominalized infinitive*' means '*by (doing sth)*', while '*Durch Verwendung*' sounds more like 'Through the use of..'

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Can you please elaborate? *Die Verwendung* and *Das Verwenden* are not really different. What's the problem with *Through the use of ...*?

Comment: You cannot expect word-by-word translations to work in all cases. Such translations may be understood but may sound weird in native speakers' ears.

Comment: I understand that both convey the same thoughts. But as a learner, I want to understand the subtle differences between them so that I can choose while writing which one would be better to use.

Comment: Your first sentence suggests that the German text was translated to English. But it was the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "-ung" is a different way of creating a noun from a verb. I think (without being able to substantiate this opinion) this device is more common in German than it is in English.

The English analogue of "Verwendung" is "usage". In English as well as German you can create a noun from "verwenden/to use" in two different ways:

> das Verwenden, die Verwendung

> the use, the usage

The translation you cited is not an exact but a colloquial one. This is because - although English and German may have some directly analogous constructs - the *usage* (the connotated meaning, respectively) of these is sometimes slightly different and a certain way of expressing things may well be grammatically correct but *somewhat off* in the other language.

The problem learning German as an English native speaker (at an advanced level) poses is that such nuances are hard to come by. I am not aware of any exact rules governing these except for the "sounds right - sounds not quite right. Duh!". "Durch Verwenden ..." is such a grammatically correct but *not quite right* translation. It would be understood by everybody but no native speaker would use it. The only consolation i can offer is that English has its own idiosyncrasies which are equally hard to grasp for Germans learning English, so we are on a par.

Comment: Your answer thoroughly addressed the concern I was having. Every language has it's own style and ways of expressing things, that sounds rather peculiar at first to foreign ears. But as a learner it is hard to grow into it, unless the literal word-to-word meaning of that phrase in native language (if possible and if such lexical terms exist) is understood.

Answer (score 0):

The substantives ending *-ung* are real substantives and easily looked up in a dictionary. I guess, it is typical to prefer them over a substantivized verb for a native speaker.  While in this case there is no real difference in meaning, this is probably more an exception than the rule considering examples like *Haltung* (in the sense of *posture* or the entirely different *attitude*, *Lüftung* in the meaning ventilation system, while *lüften* is closer to simply opening the windows).

Apart from that, the German translation you quote is not exactly convincing, since *Verwendung* is a completely blurry noun. If the person looked up a entry in the encyclopedia, it should have said so. With the given *Verwendung* a couple of other uses are imaginable, like sniffing at the paper of the book, putting it on the floor and stepping on it (or why is *dick* stated?), ...